# How can show specific number of li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show 3 `li` and after 1 second these 3 `li` will be slide up and next 3 `li` will be automatically show up in the `div.#content`

```
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li>122</li>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
        <li>fifth</li>
        <li>sixth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried `toggle` with `setTimeout` function, but it does fulfill on my requirements. I know this question may be stupid for someone but believe I really need your guideline please guide me how can i done this task. I will appreciate if someone guide me. I don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: can you share your js

Comment: you need this?http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/227/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way (not a semantic way, but) to achieve this is to wrap every 3 `<li>` and then walk through them. One way is:

```js
$(function () {
  var lis = $("ul > li");
  for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=3) {
    lis.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='slide'></div>");
  }
  $(".slide").hide();
  $(".slide:first").slideDown();
  setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".slide:visible").next(".slide").length == 0) {
      $(".slide:visible").slideUp(function () {
        $(".slide:first").slideDown();
      });
    }
    else
      $(".slide:visible").slideUp(function () {
        $(this).next(".slide").slideDown();
      });
  }, 2500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>122</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have 20 `li`?!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Just for the demo... :)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I agreed with your question

Comment: @ayazkhan Do you want to see the best way this can be achieved? You need to wrap each set of `<li>` inside another wrapper. Not to mention you need to use a semantic layout as well. You cannot have anything between a `<ul>` and a `<li>`.

Comment: Are you sure @PraveenKumar that this is _the best way this can be achieved_?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Check out the updated one. I believe this is **better** than the previous one and scalable as well.

Comment: @ayazkhan Check out the updated one. I believe this is **better** than the previous one and scalable as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I believe you are the champion.. Thank you so much for sharing knowledge. Its working...

Comment: @ayazkhan This is an infinite slider now... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** and **[`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** pseudo selectors

```js
var i = 2,
  $ul = $('#content ul'),
  int = setInterval(function() {
      $('li', $ul).slideUp();
      $('li:gt(' + i + '):lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
      i += 3;
      if (i + 1 >= $('li', $ul).length) clearInterval(int);
    },
    2000)
```

```css
#content ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>122</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If you want to slide continuously then following code can be used

```js
var i = 2,
  $ul = $('#content ul'),
  int = setInterval(function() {
      $('li', $ul).slideUp();
      $('li' + (i == -1 ? '' : ':gt(' + i + ')') + ':lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
      i += 3;
      if (i + 1 >= $('li', $ul).length) i = -1;
    },
    2000)
```

```css
#content ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>122</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: It hides after the last slide now.

Comment: where is `<li>third</li>`?

Comment: @PranavCBalan can run continuously, currently its stoping

Comment: @PranavCBalan Your script is better then others. Can you kindly adjust time at end of the loop. I means script taking some time once completed and at that #content become empty, so can you reduce this time for start quickly

Comment: @PranavCBalan please view this question and answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178145/how-can-i-reset-script-at-the-end-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("li").hide();  // this will hide all li first
$('ul li:lt(3)').show(); // this will display first 3 li from all li
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
$("#content ul li").hide();
i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  i = (i + 3) % $("#content ul li").length;
  $("#content > ul >li").slideUp();
  $("#content > ul >li:gt(" + i + ")").slideDown();
  $("#content > ul >li:gt(" + (i + 3) % $("#content ul li").length + ")").hide();
}, 1000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/229/)

Comment: Did you see the output? It displays crazy. 25 and 26 always comes.

Comment: @PraveenKumar on the fiddle?

Comment: I think ints a wrong fiddle . can you check this http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/229/

Comment: Works fine but there's a glitch in the first slide. It isn't showing the first three at all.

Comment: yup. noticed that. I think now there is no point on working on this code, since OP got the answer from you. :D

Comment: @AnoopJoshi it is start from 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

```js
var steps = 3;
$(function tick() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var top = '-=' + (steps * 31) + 'px';
    var lis = $('li:lt(' + steps + ')');
    var clones = lis.clone().appendTo('ul');
    $.when(
      $('li').animate({ top: top }, 'slow')
    ).done(function () {
      clones.remove();
      lis.appendTo('ul');
      $('li').css('top', 'auto');
      tick();
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 92px;
}
li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li><li>G</li><li>H</li></ul>
```