# How can I reset script at the end using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slide up three `li` and next three `li` are showing once previous `li` slide up. This is working properly. I'm facing problem at the end of the loop, I means all `li` slide up then it take some time to start again i want to reset quickly.

```
<div id="content">
   <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
     <li>7</li>
     <li>8</li>
     <li>9</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var i = 2,
  $ul = $('#content ul'),
  int = setInterval(function() {
      $('li', $ul).slideUp();
      $('li' + (i == -1 ? '' : ':gt(' + i + ')') + ':lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
      i += 3;
      if (i >= $('li', $ul).length) i = -1;
      if (i == -1) {
      }
    },
    2000);
```

Can anyone guide me how can I do that?

[**Demo Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5qbbhv2/)

Comment: decrease the set-interval time if you want to decrease time in sliding

Comment: @DharaParmar If i reduce the time of `setInterval()` the it will be implement on all animation

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `if` condition for that.If the value is equal or greater than `(li length) - 1` then it should start from the beginning.

```js
var i = 2,
  $ul = $('#content ul'),
  int = setInterval(function() {
      $('li', $ul).slideUp();
      $('li' + (i == -1 ? '' : ':gt(' + i + ')') + ':lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
      i += 3;
      if (i + 1 >= $('li', $ul).length) i = -1;
      // ----^----
    },
    2000);
```

```css
#content ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for what you are asking for, set the time delay:

```
var i = 2,
  $ul = $('#content ul');
var timer; // current timeout id to clear
var timeDelay = 2000; // dynamic interval

function showEm() {
  $('li', $ul).slideUp();
  $('li' + (i == -1 ? '' : ':gt(' + i + ')') + ':lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
  i += 3;
  if (i >= $('li', $ul).length) i = -1;

  if (i == -1) {
    timeDelay = 10;
  } else {
    timeDelay = 2000;
  }
}

(function repeat() {
  showEm();
  timer = setTimeout(repeat, timeDelay);
})();
```